# How to incorporate stdmetrics in gridmetrics function?

Tags: r, lidar, point-cloud, grid-metrics, lidr

I am attempting to feed the [`lidR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/index.html) gridmetrics function a list of metrics. I can generate the list of metrics within a function ([following this example](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/grid_metrics)):

```
myMetrics = function(z, i)
{
  metrics = list(
     zmean   = mean(z),
     imean   = mean(i),
     zwimean = sum(z*i)/sum(i), # Mean elevation weighted by intensities
     zimean  = mean(z*i),       # Mean products of z by intensity
     zsqmean = sqrt(mean(z^2))  # Quadratic mean
   )

   return(metrics)
}
```

And then feed the list into the `gridmetrics` function:

```
metrics = grid_metrics(lidar, myMetrics(Z, Intensity), 20)
```

However, I cannot find a way to incorporate [individual stdmetrics](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/stdmetrics) into the above `myMetrics` function.

How, for example, would I add the `zqx` or `zkurt` metrics ([from this source](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/stdmetrics)) into the `myMetrics` function, which can then be fed into the `gridmetrics` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `stdmetrics` inside your custom function like in the following example (using `stdmetrics_z`)

```
myMetrics = function(z, i)
{
  lidrmetrics = stdmetrics_z(z)

  mymetrics = list(
    zwimean = sum(z*i)/sum(i), # Mean elevation weighted by intensities
    zimean  = mean(z*i),       # Mean products of z by intensity
    zsqmean = sqrt(mean(z^2))  # Quadratic mean
  )

  return(c(mymetrics, lidrmetrics))
}

metrics = grid_metrics(lidar, myMetrics(Z, Intensity))
```

Of course if the function requires more inputs you must update the parameters of your custom function. This is documented in the examples of `help("stdmetrics")`.

Also the following works too.

```
metrics = grid_metrics(lidar, c(myMetrics(Z, Intensity), stdmetrics_z(Z)))
```