# Can a function that lists various metrics be used in `plot_metrics()`

Tags: r, lidr

I'm trying to combine various metrics to use in `plot_metrics()`. But I get an error when I run it. I tried to follow the answer from here: [How to incorporate stdmetrics in gridmetrics function?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271757/how-to-incorporate-stdmetrics-in-gridmetrics-function)

Can a function to list various metrics be used in `plot_metrics()` in the same way?

```r
library(sf)
library(lidR)

bigCat <- readLAScatalog(system.file("extdata", "example.laz", package = "rlas"))
plotDF <- data.frame(place = "plot_1", x = 339008, y = 5248001)
sf_SAMPLE <- st_as_sf(x = plotDF, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(bigCat))
plotRadius <- 11.35


myMetrics = function(z, i)
{
  res = list(
    zwimean = sum(z*i)/sum(i), # Mean elevation weighted by intensities
    zimean  = mean(z*i),       # Mean products of z by intensity
    zsqmean = sqrt(mean(z^2))  # Quadratic mean
  )
  return(res)
}

plotTreeVolAndType <- plot_metrics(bigCat,func = ~myMetrics(Z, Intensity), sf_SAMPLE, radius = plotRadius)
#> Error in as.list.default(X) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Comment: This looks good but we need a minimal reproducible example. In theory it should work. There is something wrong that I can't see in this non reproducible example

Comment: thank you, I've added 6 new lines in the code above to make it work with the lidR example file.

Comment: You found a bug. If you have a single plot it fails. If I use `plotDF = rbind(plotDF, plotDF)` to get 2 plots it works. Reported https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/issues/664